# Mockito. Mock single method which throws an exception

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a class with method `impersonate` which throws `UnsupportedOperationException`. So I want to mock only this only method. I know that I can do it with `Mockito.spy`.

```
Session session = Mockito.spy(new Session("admin", "adminSpace"));
Session imperSession = new Session("test", "testSpace");
when(session.impersonate(any(Credentials.class))).thenReturn(imperSession);
```

But the problem is that Mockito really calls `impersonate` and `UnsupportedOperationException` throws the execution. So what can I do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have to make sure mockito is not calling your method befor it's mocked you have to use the `Mockito.doXXX()` methods instead of `Mockito.when()`.

In your case the code should look like:

```
doReturn(imperSession).when(session).impersonate(any(Credentials.class));
```